# How can I find all text within a word document that matches a pattern and apply formatting on it?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document that contains :

`There will always remain a cultural difference.’56`

`All this could seriously affect the self-esteem of underprivileged students.’101`

Here ’56 and ’101 was supposed to be 56 and 101 in superscript.

As of now, I could search each number from 1 to n, for example ’56 and then manually remove ’ and highlight 56 and press **ctrl+shift+=** to make it superscript.

Is there a better, easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a wildcard find and replace.  You can split your find into "parts" and then in the replace, just refer to the parts you want to keep.

In this case, the first part is the curly apostrophe, and the second part is a string of digits.

To delete the apostrophe, just don't replace part 1.

In the screenshot below (') is part 1 and ([0-9]{1,}) is part 2.

Part 2 says find a string of one or more digits.

In the replace, we type \2 (which means reinsert part 2) and apply the superscript formatting.

The result is the apostrophe is deleted and the number becomes superscript.

[image]

Comment: Damn! How do you know all this?

Comment: A few years ago I came across a really good article at https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm - now I see opportunities to use a wildcard find and replace everywhere :-)